How to optimize rendering for a StatusBadge component in a large DataTable using useState and useEffect?
I have a React component called StatusBadge that I'm using in a large DataTable. This component accepts a status prop and updates its background color based on the value of status using useState and useEffect. Here is a simplified version of the component:
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const StatusBadge:FC = ({ status }) => {
  const [BackgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("bg-white");

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (status) {
      case IN_PROGRESS:
        setBackgroundColor("bg-yellow-500");
        break;
      case VALIDATED:
        setBackgroundColor("bg-lime-500");
        break;
      case TO_REVIEW:
        setBackgroundColor("bg-orange-500");
    }
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <div
      className={BackgroundColor}
    >
      {status}
    </div>
  );
};

export default StatusBadge;


I am concerned about the performance implications when rendering a large number of these badges in a DataTable. Specifically:
How often will this component re-render? Given that the status prop may change, I’m worried about unnecessary re-renders impacting performance.
Is using useState and useEffect a good approach here? Would there be a more efficient way to handle this component, especially to minimize re-renders? Should I consider a different pattern or optimization technique for better performance?
Any advice or best practices on optimizing this component would be greatly appreciated!

This is why you don't need an effect: https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes

If you summarize the link ,that you share it with me what is your opinion, it would make easyer for me .thx

There's no problem in using the state for this case. But considering the StatusBadge is an atomic component, there's no need to use state management just to apply a style.
Let's think of the status props as a value that is coming from the parent and could be changed over time/in real-time. Assuming that value is going to affect any parameters inside this badge component, we can make a defined list of styles for your badge and accept the status as a listening parameter. As react handles this props change in its VDOM automatically and re-render after that.
You can create a pre-defined record that contains cases as the keys with values ​​from the style class that will be used according to the status.
const backgroundVariants = {
   IN_PROGRESS: 'bg-yellow-500',
   VALIDATED: 'bg-lime-500',
   TO_REVIEW: 'bg-orange-500',
   DEFAULT: 'bg-white',
}

const StatusBadge:FC = ({ status = 'DEFAULT' }) => (
   <div className={backgroundVariants[status]}>
     {status}
   </div>
)

export default StatusBadge


How about useEffect in this case, as I said this component will render inside a row in the datatable,  and the datatable has a lot of data

When you map each row of data, you can also pass the status value to the badge. The badge style changes according to the row. So you won't have more computation inside that atomic component. In this case, it all happens bound to the row component.

Meaning delete useState and useEffect ?

Yeah, you don't need them in such a case.

I'm looking for the raison why I don't need them , because in the first time you said it is not problem to use the useState and then you said  don't need them , I want a logic explanation.

I must say that using useState for this case is not a problem as it is a beginner-friendly approach. But, if your application becomes more complex, it's not necessary to use the useState for such a small problem that could lead to unpredictable re-renders. Just make it simple.

The project is very complex and im working in professionalenvironment that is why im so wary about the performance of the app, sometimes I have two datatable in the same page , with loading a huge data, and putting this component for each row, is useState and useEffect here can cause a problem,  I'm wondering .
